# D/ProfileInstaller(14242): Installing profile for com.example.instagram_clone

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error after completing the app instagram clone.
I haven't run the app for a while so when I came back running the app it is giving me this error does anyone know the solution?

The error:

```
I/instagram_clon(14242): Compiler allocated 5171KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
D/ProfileInstaller(14242): Installing profile for com.example.instagram_clone
```

And I am running on the real device, and I am seeing a black screen with this error in the terminal. What should I do?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your github code

Answer (score 3):

I was facing this issue when my emulator did not have an active internet connection. Make sure your emulator/phone and laptop are connected to internet.

(My app was using Supabase)

Also verify if you app makes API calls to unreachable endpoints if you are connected to internet.

Answer (score -1):

more like you copy and pasted the code lol, changing the api key may work

OR

remove the following lines of code from main.dart, before first run of your app (if using firebase), you may keep the main function async:

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

you can add it later once the app is configured on the first run.

funny how you 'built' the app by yourself but are not aware of this little fix which everybody learns from a bit of hit and trial

Comment: nope, the thing is I deleted the android folder by mistake since then I am getting this error

Answer (score -1):

I understand the issue you're facing, and there are several potential solutions you can try to resolve it.

Run flutter clean in your terminal to clean the build artifacts and start with a fresh build.

If the problem persists, consider making a fresh copy of your Android folder, as this can sometimes resolve persistent issues.

However, if the error still persists after trying the above steps, it's possible that the hang-up is related to the initialization of external services like Firebase, AWS, or other APIs. Specifically, if you have used an await statement during the initialization process, it might lead to a long wait during profile initialization.

To address this, locate the main function in your code, and if you find an await statement for initializing Firebase or any other cloud resources, remove it. The proper way to set up SDKs for cloud resources is through their respective initialization methods without using await during app initialization

For example, instead of this:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(); // REMOVE THIS LINE
```

Do This

```
void main() {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
Firebase.initializeApp(); // Proper initialization without await
runApp(const MyApp());
}
```